# Data did not display in pdf using php

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I do not know why there is no any data displaying, it is just display the folder data which i have hard code it. But it won't display any data from the database even the database have data. Can any one help out? i have figured it out for whole day already, even this question might duplicate and i can't search the answer i want so might need someone help. Appreciate.

Below is the code for pdf call 'generate_pdf.php'

```
    <?php
require_once 'config.php';
require 'fpdf181/fpdf.php';

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from images where Id = '".isset($_POST['pdfId'])."'");
$gpdf=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$id = $gpdf['Id'];              //"ID";
$txt = $gpdf['CompanyN'];       //"Kamaya";
$txt2 = $gpdf['ContactP'];      //"Sales";
$txt3 = $gpdf['Email'];         //"sss@kamaya.com.my";
$chk = $gpdf['checkbox'];       //"KJ";
$chk1 = $gpdf['Others'];        //"Others";
$txt5 = $gpdf['Othersinput'];   //"Others";
$txt6 = $gpdf['SalesStaff'];    //salesstaff
$txt7 = $gpdf['LotNo'];         //"886515154M";
$txt8 = $gpdf['CusPartNo'];     //"cus123456";
$txt9 = $gpdf['Title'];         //"cannot work";
$chk2 = $gpdf['checkbox2'];
$chk9 = $gpdf['process'];
$txt10 = $gpdf['inputbox2'];    //"JIG STACKING";
$chk10 = $gpdf['Others2'];
$txt24 = $gpdf['Othersinput2'];
$txt11 = $gpdf['Rate'];         //"10%";
$txt12 = $gpdf['FailDate'];     //"2020-09-06"; 
$chk3 = $gpdf['checkbox3'];     //"return";
$txt14 = $gpdf['ETA'];          //"2020-09-06";
$txt15 = $gpdf['Quantity'];     //"5";
$chk4 = $gpdf['checkbox4'];     //"No required";
$txt17 = $gpdf['ETD'];          //"2020-09-06";
$txt18 = $gpdf['Quantity2'];    //"5";
$chk5 = $gpdf['checkbox5'];     //"required";
$chk6 = $gpdf['Method'];        //"Phone";
$txt19 = $gpdf['VisitBy'];      //"me";
$txt20 = $gpdf['visitDate'];    //"2020-09-06";
$txt21 = $gpdf['Reportdate'];   //"2020-09-06";
$txt22 = $gpdf['Textarea'];     //"qqwweerrttyyuuiiooppllkkjjhhggffddssaazxxzxccvvbnm.,lpiujhhhgvasgvybagfvabfvgyabuibaubfvuigaubvuailbuaubkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk";



$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P','A4',0);
    
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    //$pdf->SetXY(7,5);
    $pdf->Multicell(120,5,"KAMAYA ELECTRIC (M) SDN.BHD\nCUSTOMER COMPLAINT SHEET",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(130,10);
    $pdf->Multicell(69,5,"Date Issued :".date('yy-m-d'),1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(130,15);
    $pdf->Multicell(69,5,"Report No :".$id,1,"C");
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,7.5,"Complaint\nInitiator",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,20);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Co.Name :".$txt,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,25);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Contact Person: ".$txt2,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,30);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Email / Contact No: ".$txt3,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,7.5,"Sales\nOffice",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,35);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,$chk,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,40);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,$chk1." ".$txt5,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,45);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Sales Staff : ".$txt6,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,10,"Product",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,50);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Lot No : ".$txt7,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,55);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Customer Part No : ".$txt8,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,15,"Failure",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,60);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Title : ".$txt9,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,65);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Scene : ".$chk2." \t ",1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,65);
    $pdf->Write(5,$chk9. "" . $txt10);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,65);
    $pdf->Write(5,$chk10. "" . $txt24);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,70);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Rate : ".$txt11." \t "."Date :".$txt12,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,7.5,"Failure\nSample",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,75);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,8,$chk3." \t "."ETA :".$txt14,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,83);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,7,"Quantity :".$txt15,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,15,"Replacement",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,90);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,8,$chk4." \t "."ETD :".$txt17,1);
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,98);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,7,"Quantity :".$txt18,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,15,"Reply",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,105);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,$chk5."\t Method : ".$chk6,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(36,110);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Visit By : ".$txt19."\t Date : ".$txt20,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(36,115);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,"Report Required Date : ".$txt21,1);
    
    $pdf->Multicell(26,15,"Failure Details\n(Attached photo if available)",1,"C");
    
    $pdf->SetXY(36,120);
    $pdf->Multicell(163,5,$txt22,1);
    
//display image and document
$temp = "37";
$temp2 = "154";
$temp3 = "51";
$temp4 = "185";
$imgrow=0;
$allFiles1 = scandir("F:/xampp/htdocs/new3/uploads/KM2009001");
$files1 = array_diff($allFiles1, array('.', '..')); // To remove . and .. 
foreach($files1 as $file1)
{
    $tt = "F:/xampp/htdocs/new3/uploads/KM2009001"."/".$file1;
    
    if(is_file($tt)){
        $allowed = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg');
        $ext = pathinfo($tt, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
            $imgrow ++;
            $pdf->SetXY(37,154);
            if($imgrow === 1)
            {
                $pdf->Image($tt,$temp,$temp2,30,20);
                $temp+=40;
            }
            $imgrow=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $pdf->SetXY($temp3,$temp4);
            $file = basename($tt,$file1);
            $pdf->DisplayPreferences('DisplayDocTitle');
            $pdf->Write(5,$file);
            $temp4 += 5;
            
        }
        
    }
}
$pdf->Line(36,180,199,180);
$pdf->Line(199,180,199,120);

$pdf->SetXY(10,180);
$pdf->Multicell(26,15,"Attachments\n(if available)",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(36,180);
$pdf->Multicell(15,5," NO ",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(36,185);
$pdf->Multicell(15,5," 1 ",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(36,190);
$pdf->Multicell(15,5," 2 ",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(36,195);
$pdf->Multicell(15,5," 3 ",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(36,200);
$pdf->Multicell(15,5," 4 ",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(36,205);
$pdf->Multicell(15,5," 5 ",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(51,180);
$pdf->Multicell(148,5,"Attachments",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(51,185);
$pdf->Multicell(148,5,"",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(51,190);
$pdf->Multicell(148,5,"",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(51,195);
$pdf->Multicell(148,5,"",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(51,200);
$pdf->Multicell(148,5,"",1,"C");
$pdf->SetXY(51,205);
$pdf->Multicell(148,5,"",1,"C");
 
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

This is the form that can select the ID and generate the PDF by clicking the generate button 'formselect.php'

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>8D Generator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST' action='generate_pdf.php'>
            <select name='pdfID'>
                <?php
                    $query=mysqli_query($conn,'select * from images');
                    while($gpdf=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        echo "<option value='".$gpdf['Id']."'>".$gpdf['Id']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type='submit' value='Generate'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should be display out in a pdf, but now the output only display the design of the pdf all data it wont display. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Have you test if query is correct?

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have already fixed the problem which at the 'formselect.php' the select tag and i assigned the name is pdfID, then looked back the 'generate_pdf.php' it was found that i have typo error which is pdfId then i change back to pdfID and it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to correct this line (see @Simone Rossaini comment):

```
/* error:
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from images where Id = '".isset($_POST['pdfId'])."'");
*/
```

because the [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.isset.php) function returns a `boolean` (true or false). So, you query will never work, because the `Id` would be invalid. (Id should be a string or an int, right?)

Change the query to something like this:

```
$pdf_id = isset($_POST['pdfId']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pdfId']) : "";
if (empty($pdf_id)) {
  // no id was given -> alert the user
  die('Error: no id!');
}

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from images where Id = '".$pdf_id."'");
```

Did it work? Try adding a `var_dump($gpdf);` after running the query, to check you get the correct data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have already fixed the problem which at the 'formselect.php' the select tag and i assigned the name is pdfID, then looked back the 'generate_pdf.php' it was found that i have typo error which is pdfId then i change back to pdfID and it works.